# Access to the data of a call in axios javascript

Tags: javascript, json, get, axios

I am trying to access a json that returns a call to the api through axios, but the problem is that it returns it like this, how can I access Province:name

I tried response.data.province:name but it shows an error

```
{ "Province:name": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Álava",
  "provinceCode": "1",
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Albacete",
  "provinceCode": "2",
 }
]}
```

Comment: response.data["Province:name"] ?

Comment: if that worked!!,  I had tried response.data[Province:name] and it didn't work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
const name = response.data["Province:name"];
console.log(name);
```